# Running Powershell Script on Multiple Systems from one system

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to deploy this script on multiple VMs Hosted on Vcenter.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Install-OMS-Agent-with-2c9c99ab

The script mentioned on the above link is the script it is for installing OMS agent on the single server.

Comment: How about group policy instead? Or Powershell's fan-out remoting?

Comment: any supporting link for that?

Comment: If you have problems finding relevant documentation, please edit the question and add more details. Mention the search engine used (not all are good for technical searches) and which keyword combinations were looked for. Also, see help about how to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet can run scripts in parallel on remote systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` on a list of hostnames and use `Invoke-Command` on each hostname from there.

Example:

```
$servers = Get-Content servers.txt

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        .\InstallOMSAgent.ps1
    }
}
```

Comment: Still this requires logging into every and enabling PSRemoting

Comment: Correct. To use powershell remotely you will need to enable powershell remoting.. :p But I wouldn't log in to each machine, just use group policy to enable WinRM on your servers automatically.